# PyHook mouse event

Tags: python, pyhook, pyautogui

I wrote a small program in Python, which executes the function "go" when I press the left mouse button. My intention however is to execute go only while I hold LMB. If I release LMB it should cancel "go". Finally when canceld or successfully executed it should be ready to do the same when I press LMB again.

Here is the code:

```
import pyHook
import pythoncom
import pyautogui
from time import sleep
pyautogui.size()

width, height = pyautogui.size()


def go(event):

    sleep(0.099)
    pyautogui.moveRel(4, 19, duration=0.099)
    pyautogui.moveRel(-4, 7, duration=0.099)
    pyautogui.moveRel(-3, 29, duration=0.099)
    pyautogui.moveRel(-1, 31, duration=0.099)
    pyautogui.moveRel(13, 31, duration=0.099)
    pyautogui.moveRel(8, 28, duration=0.099)
    pyautogui.moveRel(13, 21, duration=0.099)
    pyautogui.moveRel(-17, 12, duration=0.099)
    pyautogui.moveRel(-42, -3, duration=0.099)
    pyautogui.moveRel(-21, 2, duration=0.099)
    pyautogui.moveRel(-15, 7, duration=0.099)
    pyautogui.moveRel(12, 11, duration=0.099)
    pyautogui.moveRel(-26, -8, duration=0.099)
    pyautogui.moveRel(-3, 4, duration=0.099)
    pyautogui.moveRel(40, 1, duration=0.099)
    pyautogui.moveRel(19, 7, duration=0.099)
    pyautogui.moveRel(14, 10, duration=0.099)
    pyautogui.moveRel(27, 0, duration=0.099)
    pyautogui.moveRel(33, -10, duration=0.099)
    pyautogui.moveRel(-21, -2, duration=0.099)
    pyautogui.moveRel(7, 3, duration=0.099)
    pyautogui.moveRel(-7, 9, duration=0.099)
    pyautogui.moveRel(-8, 4, duration=0.099)
    pyautogui.moveRel(19, -3, duration=0.099)
    pyautogui.moveRel(5, 6, duration=0.099)
    pyautogui.moveRel(-20, -1, duration=0.099)
    pyautogui.moveRel(-33, -4, duration=0.099)
    pyautogui.moveRel(-45, -21, duration=0.099)
    pyautogui.moveRel(-14, 1, duration=0.099)
    return True



hm = pyHook.HookManager()
hm.SubscribeMouseLeftDown(go)
hm.HookMouse()
pythoncom.PumpMessages()
hm.UnhookMouse()
```

Comment: Is all of that code necessary to explain your question?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that all your code in go() is sequential. If it were iterative, you could've checked for an event or bool to be triggered in that loop and abort go(). The bool/event could be triggered on SubscribeMouseLeftUp(). This cannot be done iteratively in your case.

You could perhaps try and pepper a check for trigger in your go() method its not clean but it could do the job, be it in a very inefficient manner.

Thirdly, depending on how hooks and gui work in threads you could offload go() to a thread. Kick that thread off on MouseDown and abort/kill it on MouseUp.